# Assigning value to a textfield, dependent on another textfield, using conditional statements

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am an amateur in multi-language programming, but I have an MVC model coming up, and this is my issue:

The following code works 100%. If the value of the first textbox is changed, the second textbox gets the user name as value.

```
$("#solDate").change(function () {
             $("#solvedBy").val('@uName');
         });

My textboxes:

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Solution_Date, new { @id = "solDate", @class = "one", @type = "datetime"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Solved_by, new { @id = "solvedBy", @readonly = "true", htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control" } })
```

..and my C# variable (uName):

```
@{
    var uName = User.Identity.Name.ToString().Substring(3);
 }
```

As I said, this works perfectly. The problem is, that I want to remove the user name if the value of the first textbox is deleted. I've come up with the following solution, which doesn't work:

```
$("#solDate").change(function () {
            if (("#solDate").length < 1) {
                $("#solvedBy").val('');
            }
            else {
                $("#solvedBy").val('@uName');
            }
        });
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would do the trick, get value and trim it to remove empty spaces. Then check if its `''`:

```
$("#solDate").change(function () {
    if ( $(this).val().trim() == '' ) {
        $("#solvedBy").val('');
    } else {
        $("#solvedBy").val('@uName');
    }
});
```

Good luck have fun!

Comment: This is safer since .trim does not exist on all platforms: 
`var val = $.trim(this.value)===""?"":"@uName";
 $("#solvedBy").val(val);`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `$` character here:

```
if ($("#solDate").length < 1) {
```

Alternatively, you could use `$(this)` instead of `$("#solDate")` too.

Comment: Thanks, that was the real problem. Such a silly thing!